# How to use csrf token in javascript with django api

Tags: javascript, django, csrf

I wish to post data from javascript to an api implemented in django. But I cannot get beyond the  csrf token

**settings.py**

```
...
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8888'
]
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
...
```

**views.py**

```
class SaveArchive(View):
    ...
    @requires_csrf_token
    def post(self, request, params):
        ...
```

**api.js**

```
...
async function sendDataToAPI(url, post_data) {
    let endpoint = `${process.env.API_DOMAIN}${url}/`;

    var getToken= new XMLHttpRequest();
    getToken.open("POST", endpoint, true);
    getToken.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    getToken.send(JSON.stringify(post_data));
    return;
...
```

I get the error on the django server

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/save-archive/{...}/
```

What needs changing?

Answer (score 0):

Django provide way for storing the csrf token in the cookie of current request. After, you can retrieve simply by getting it in cookie.

Django documentation can help you with code example for AJAX cases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: I have read the docs!, but my django app does not seem to be providing  the csrf token

Comment: Have you a form tag in your template ? What happen if your add `{% csrf_token %}` in your template ?

Comment: No - I am using Django as an API not to render forms

Comment: If you want to use django as API, you have to use a extension for managing the authentication system (DRf, JWT...etc)